# Firebase cloud function local code changes are not reflected in emulators

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to develop API for my apps using Firebase cloud functions.
Following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) site to use the firebase emulator suite for development and testing locally.

**Issue: The changes are not reflected in the locally emulated functions.**

**Steps:**

1. **index.js:**

   ```
   exports.test = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
      response.status(200).send("First");
   });
   ```
2. Successfully deployed the `test` method.

   ```
   firebase deploy --only functions:test
   ```
3. In Postman made the following GET request.

   ```
    https://us-central1-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/test
   ```

   Result: First
   Status: 200 OK
4. Started the emulators:

   ```
   firebase emulators:start --only functions
   ```
5. In Postman made the following GET request.

   ```
    http://localhost:5001/<project-name>/us-central1/indexTest
   ```

   Result: First
   Status: 200 OK
   Same as the actual deployed function.
6. **Changed the function code to:**

   ```
   exports.test = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
       response.status(200).send("Second");
   });
   ```
7. Getting the same result as before when hitting the emulated function in localhost. The changes are not reflected.

Also, tried stopping the emulator and starting it again. No luck.

Comment: To be clear, are you expecting the emulator to reload the code dynamically after you change it?  Did you save the file?  If you think the emulator is not working correctly, you should file a bug on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @DougStevenson, 
I have saved the file. Dynamically reload the code changes, load the code changes after restarting the emulator anything is fine. It is not loading the changes in any way until the code is deployed to production, which makes local emulators pointless.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I have filed a bug as suggested: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2823.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had raised an issue in the firebase-tools repo as suggested by DougStevenson.
Got the issue resolved with Sam Stern's support.

Posting the solution here for anyone else who gets stuck in the same issue.

**Solution:**

1. After every change to the ts files, run "npm run build" to compile the code again.
2. Change `"build": "tsc"` to `"build": "tsc -w"` in `package.json` if you want to auto-compile after every change.