# firebase emulator cannot refresh dynamic import Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

**Background**
I use dynamic import for Firebase Functions to reduce cold start time based on this post: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/organize-cloud-functions-for-max-cold-start-performance-and-readability-with-typescript-and-9261ee8450f0

`index.ts` under `functions` folder has only one line

```js
exports.consent = require("./myFunctionGroup");
```

`index.ts` under `functions/myFunctionGroup`

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return await (await import("./helloWorld")).default(data, context);
});
```

Content of `helloWorld.ts` under `functions/myFunctionGroup`

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export default async (
  data: {},
  context: functions.https.CallableContext
) => {
    return "hello";
}
```

There is no problem when the emulator first launched as it return "hello" correctly. However, when I change to return to 'return "world";', even though the emulator seems to be aware of the change and prints `✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source:...`, it still return the old value of hello. Maybe it has some kind of cache for the original imported module. When I restart process again, then it will then print "world".

**Question**:
Is there any setting to make the emulator aware my change and force to clear the Functions cache? I tried to use debugger and it realized my code has changed so that I can step through the new code. It's just not working for the Firebase emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was expected behavior,any changes/modification in the code after running the emulator will not be reflected. You can also refer to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Code,as%20you%20save.):

> Note:Code changes you make during an active session are automatically
> reloaded by the emulator. If your code needs to be transpiled
> (TypeScript, React) make sure to do so before running the emulator.
> You can run your transpiler in watch mode with commands like tsc -w to
> transpile and reload code automatically as you save.

You can follow the below steps,As mentioned in this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64876762/18265638)

> - After every change to the ts files, run "npm run build" to compile the code again.
> - Change "build": "tsc" to "build": "tsc -w" in package.json if you want to auto-compile after every change.

There is a bug raised for this at [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4691) which is still open you can track the updates there.